# Tomcat 404 Page With Spring Form

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

In my web.xml page I have the 404 error mapped to a jsp page as:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorPages/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The redirect on 404 works fine. I get to error404.jsp. The problem is that I have a spring form on the page (a search form that is on EVERY page) which causes errors because the target object is not in the model. I get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor
>   plain target object for bean name 'searchCriteria' available as request attribute

I'd like to have this search form on every page, including the error pages. Is there any way to do this? I realize that 404 as I have it configured above doesn't go to a servlet... so how do I get the request attribute into the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to map the error pages to a servlet. Within the servlet you can add things to your model just like you can in any other servlet. To map error pages to a servlet, add something like the following to your web.xml file:

```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/generalError</location>
  </error-page>
```

where "error" is the servlet name and "generalError" is the request mapping.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to code the search form as plain HTML in your JSP/template, so that you remove any dependency on the form binding object. For a simple search form with a text input and submit button, this should not be a problem.

Comment: That's true, but then I have to maintain the form twice: one spring form based form and one static form. I would like to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: I was assuming you were using Sitemesh or Tiles, so there is normally only one instance of a decorator that you need to maintain. If not, you could use a JSP tag file or simply include a JSPF file, to avoid maintaining two instances of the form? This assumes you would maintain a HTML version... you can still get "sticky" values by doing something like `<input type="text" name="query" value="${param.query}"/>`.

Comment: Either way, I still have to maintain 2 forms that are identical. Why bother with the spring form? I might as well just use a vanilla form that can be used on every page.